# Два тире в регулярном выражении

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день, люди добрые. 
В регулярных выражениях недавно, мучает одна строка... ну ни как не поддаётся.

```
preg_match("/^([A-z_0-9\$\s\-]+)(|\-([a-z24]+))$/i", $urlprop['func'], $urllogin22);
```

Вот собственно строка регулярки.

В urlprop хранится строка урл, в которой может быть 2 положения:

> - названиеТовара
> - названиеТовара-Опция

Проблема кроется в том что название товара может содержать тире "-" и регулярка уже не разбивает урл на "названиеТовара" и "Опция".

Подскажите что в моём выражении не так и как это можно было бы исправить?

Comment: Так она и для "названиеТовара-Опция" не работает.

Comment: Она работает на поиск названиеТовара даже если в нём тире. А мне бы надо что бы можно было определять еще и опцию, не разбирая при этом названиеТовара на части через тире

Comment: @ПетрЛикров а `названиеТовара` всегда имеет такой формат? То есть, название товара всегда записано кэмел-кейсом? Если можете, приведите пример реального названия.

Comment: Нет =) просто так красивее видится и по моему легко читается. url: site_ru/catalog/verbljuzhiishrift-vzgrev-option

Comment: @ПетрЛикров запостил **[ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/764805/185343)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За самый рабочий ответ спасибо Nik'у

```
$opt = str_replace('-','',substr($urlprop['func'], strrpos($urlprop['func'], '-')));
$options = array('option1','option2','option3','option4');

if(in_array($opt,$options)){
    // если есть опция
}else{
    // если последнее слово после тире не подходит ни под одну из опций
}
```

как оказалось проще решить эту проблему вообще без регулярного выражения =)

Answer (score 2):

Думаю изначально проблема не в регулярном выражении, а в логике, приведу пример для наглядности:
Есть вот такие URL:

```
Товар-Опция
Товар-товар-Опция
Товар-товар-товар-Опция
```

И с помощью `Look ahead` мы делим строку по последнему знаку `-`:

```
preg_match("/^(.*)(?=-)[-*](.*)$/i", $urlprop['func'], $urllogin22);
var_dump($urllogin22);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "Товар-Опция"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Товар"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Опция"
}
```

Во всех 3х вариантах отработает всё как нужно, но если будет товар который без категории:

```
Товар-товар
```

И товар с категорией с первого примера:

```
Товар-Опция
```

Для регулярки это тоже самое, вам нужно менять структуру url чтобы понимать точно где товар где опция.

Answer (score 2):

Если строка имеет формат "*Название-товара-Опция*", то в имя товара будет сохранена часть "*Название-товара*", а в опцию "*Опция*".

Если опция не указана, то в имени товара будет строка "*Название-товара*"

```
$str = 'НазваниеТовара-Опция';
$option = '';
preg_match_all('~\w+-?\w+~u', $str, $a);
count($a[0]) > 1 ? list($name, $option) = $a[0] : $name = $a[0];

var_dump($name, $option);
```

**UPD:** Если опции заранее известны, тогда можно обойтись без регулярных выражений:

```
$url = 'НазваниеТовара-option1';

$temp = explode('-', $url);
$option = array_pop($temp);
$options = ['option1', 'option2', 'option3', 'option4'];

if (($k = array_search($option, $options)) !== false) {
    echo 'Товар: '. join($temp) . '<br>Опции: ' . $options[$k];
}
```

Comment: Опять же если будет "НазваниеТовара-Опция" (название без тире) - то выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: @ПетрЛикров какую ошибку? Текст ошибки скопируйте сюда, пожалуйста, и я подправлю свой ответ.

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/framework/list.php on line 6
string(22) "nazvaniebeztire-option1" NULL

Comment: @ПетрЛикров ответ подправил. Ошибок не будет, но и разделения на Имя_Опция при таком фомате входящей строки тоже не будет. Вам нужно добавлять некий разделитель, и потом по этому разделителю ориентироваться.

Comment: Спасибо большое за включение. Наиболее рабочий вариант без регулярок вообще - от Nik'a прозвучал в комментариях к одному из ответов выше.

Comment: @ПетрЛикров да, тут и без регулярок можно обойтись. Я в ответ добавил вариант без регулярных выражений.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться preg_split c Negative Lookahead, который найдет последний дефис в строке

```
list($name, $option) = preg_split('/\-(?!.*\-)/', 'Название-товара-Опция');
echo $name.'<>',$option; // Название-товара<>Опция
```

Comment: А как быть если в ссылке положение "НазваниеТовара" имеет тире, получается он разобьёт "названиеТовара" на полу-название и якобы-опцию

Comment: @ПетрЛикров а как мы можем тогда понять, что есть опция, а что есть название товара. Если опции может не быть, а в названии может быть тире, то тут нельзя однозначно понять, если нет каких-то отличительных свойств у опции.

Comment: А если допустим известны названия опций, т.е. их 10 штук, и они предопределены... это изменит что нибудь?

Comment: если известен список - да

Comment: @ПетрЛикров в таком случае здесь вообще не нужны регулярки. Получить опцию можем так: `$opt = substr($urllogin, strrpos($urllogin, '-'));if(!in_array($opt, $option)) $opt = ''; `. В случае, если опции нет, она будет равна пустой строке.